# Could not open web page from web service

Tags: vb.net, web-services

It is a simple program that opens a web site in a web service written in VB .NET.

It works fine when I test it in Visual Studio, but after applying it to IIS, I can't open the Web Page.

```
            cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamRet)
            cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[usp_ins_inq_log]"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim ReturnVal As Int32 = cmd.Parameters("@P_OutId").Value

            conn.Close()


            sUrl = sUrl + "?Id=" + ReturnVal.ToString()

            Process.Start("chrome.exe", sUrl)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is going to work from a webservice, or if it does there is a whole heap of security in IIS that will need to be compromised.  IIS by default goes a long way to explicitly prevent spawning external processes.  What exact problem are you trying to solve with this solution, perhaps we could suggest some alternatives?

Comment: Where is the database located? Has @P_OutId been added to the parameters collection? Show that code. Where do you dispose the command and connection. Show that code. The Add(Object) is expecting an SQLParamter. Is ParamRet a paramer object. What are its properties. Have you set the CommandType property? Show the code.

Comment: Actually, we are making a web service that acts as a middle man.
When a user click a button in the main program we should open a web page showing the items and return the content as xml to the main program when it is selected.

Comment: I found the reason. the process could not start the web browser from the IIS since security reason. https://forums.asp.net/t/1887415.aspx?Process+Start+explorer+exe+n+path+Doesn+t+work

Comment: Could I ask, what's the point of the middle man?  Why not have the button click in your main program go straight to where it needs to and get the XML directly?  I'm only asking because allowing IIS to spawn processes is a rather large security hole your opening.  Perhaps, this an intranet app and doesn't really matter?